# Solve the third order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

Is it possible to solve this differential equation analytically?

Comment: You can use separation of variables, but you may need the second order derivative for a boundary condition.

Comment: Is $L_2(t)$ specified?  That's the sticking point: BTW it makes separation of variables impossible.

Comment: I have the feeling that the corresponding elliptic equation has no solution in $L^2(0L)$ (let alone on an interval with moving boundary), i.e., the spectrum of the differential operator is too large for the third derivative to generate a semigroup on $L^2(0,L)$; and therefore there is no solution for general $F_0$.